# Why does the discrete bode plot look like the following and if possible explain the black vertical line at the end for an averaging filter

Tags: fourier-analysis, control-theory, average, z-transform

Why in the attached image for a simple 3 point moving average that has been converted into a TF (z domain) is there a wired dip? It seems that when I change the sampling time, the dip shifts to the right. And why does the black veritable line at the end seem to be equal to $\pi/T$? It looks like the black line is $2x$ frequency of the systems bandwidth so I'm assuming it is related to the Shanon limit for sampling? In what world does the output to a moving average just suddenly cease to exist, or go to zero at the dip? [The attached reference bode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XK0c.png)

I am in the 1st year of control stuff. Thanks for the help

Comment: You should ask this question on the Stack Exchange [dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/27877/34431) site

Comment: So the z domain transfer function that you are considering is:$$\frac{z^2+z+1}{3\,z^2}$$

Comment: @JeanMarie hi my apologies i didnt know that was a thing! I shall do

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen yeah thats the one

Comment: Don't apologize !